# Interpreting semivariogram from ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, interpolation, spatial-statistics, modelling

Am having an output for semivariogram from ArcGIS Pro as per below. However, the distance looks small.

Is there a way to adjust the distance?

Not only that, how best can I interpret the x and y values as per this output.

[image]

Comment: Please don't link to images, include them in your post.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answers:**

The distance looks small because the variogram show that the points within this distance become spatially independent from one another. You can adjust the distance, but this won't make the empirical model any different.

The X axis shows the lag distance between the points in the dataset.

The Y axis represents the variance between these point.

But more important questions here are:

**What kind of data are we looking at?**

The lag size seems to be extremely small. The variogram show that a distance of +- 0.0002 meters the points no longer have any influence on each other. If this doesn't make sense for what the data actually represents, than either the data is faulty or somewhere in the process a mistake has been made.

**How good is your knowledge about variograms and Kriging?**

This is so important in creating these models. Otherwise the model (without being able to explain the choices made in creating the model) is useless.

Now, Kriging and variograms are complex but luckily ESRI provides some great documentation on [semi variance modeling](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geostatistical-analyst/semivariogram-and-covariance-functions.htm).

Especially the [empirical model and the theoretical fitted model](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geostatistical-analyst/fitting-a-model-to-the-empirical-semivariogram.htm) and the [nugget, sill and range](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geostatistical-analyst/understanding-a-semivariogram-the-range-sill-and-nugget.htm) are important to understand.

Assuming you want to use the semi-variogram to perform Kriging you should also have a extensive read through [this](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geostatistical-analyst/kriging-in-geostatistical-analyst.htm).
Some more theoretical explanation videos that I always recommend can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-hnxGq74q0) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-IB4_QL7Oc&t=741s).